# enable submit when date is selected from datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, submit

submit button gets enabled when I type date manually but when I select it from datepicker it does not gets enabled

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="txt" onkeyup="manage(this)" class="form-control" name=<?php echo 'actual_date__' . $cur['id'] . '__' . $cur['master_id'] ?> value="<?php echo $filtered_row_result1["actual_date"] ?? ''; ?>" >
    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
</body>
<script>
    function manage(txt) {
        var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
        if (txt.value != '') {
            bt.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            bt.disabled = true;
        }
    }
<script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="txt" onchange="manage(this)" class="form-control" name="_name" value="1990-01-01" >
    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
</body>
<script>
    function manage(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
        let bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
        if (txt.value != '') {
            bt.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            bt.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

check out this solution. I changed the input name - because I can't use php here. change to yours

Comment: thanks @WiatroBosy It works but I do not want to change the value attribute,Value should be fetched from database which is inserted before ,so maintaining this conditions can we obtain my query

Comment: name and value - I changed only because php doesn't work on stackoverflow - replace name and value with your php code.

Answer (score 0):

Use onchange instead of onkeyup

```js
function manage(txt) {
  var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
  if (txt.value != '') {
    bt.disabled = false;
  } else {
    bt.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="date" id="txt" onchange="manage(this)" class="form-control" name=<?php echo 'actual_date__' . $cur[ 'id'] . '__' . $cur[ 'master_id'] ?> value="
  <?php echo $filtered_row_result1["actual_date"] ?? ''; ?>" >
  <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked. Appreciated @Nikhil Sawant

Comment: @Nikhil Sawant have you checked that your snippet has no errors ?

Comment: @Nikhil Sawant for file upload field neither onchange nor onkeyup working,which can be used ? do you have any idea?

Comment: @CodeRak Can you share the code snippet ? So that I can check the cause of  issue.

Comment: @NikhilSawant thanks for asking, Anyway I solved the issue

Comment: @CodeRak  Okay great!. Will you please accept the answer if it worked for you.